# How can i created unit testing to Graphql application with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, graphql

I created an application with Laravel using Graphql. But I dont how to create my unit tests. Only do it simple request with PHPUnit or have other better way to do it?

Example Query Graphql in Laravel:

```
class ClientQuery extends Query
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'ClientQuery',
        'description' => 'A query'
    ];

    public function type()
    {
       return GraphQL::type("Client");
    }

    public function args()
    {
       return [
            'id' => [
                 'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::int()),
            ],
       ];
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args, $context, ResolveInfo $info)
    {
      return Client::find($args['id']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using GraphQL like you.
Because I've used GraphQL files to describe my data model, I have only my resolver in PHP (like you no?).

I think you can create Unit test but it is not necessary because is the role of data model to avoid errors of Type. But you can make it to perform a better product/platform yes.

In this way, Integration tests are very important, to test resolvers.

I'm currently using API call to test resolvers, but it can change because I'm not an expert and I don't think it's the better way but for now that make the job.